# using the Maybe monad with monadic actions

Tags: haskell

When I have for instance a `Maybe` value, and I want to apply something on it when it's a `Just` or just keep a `Nothing` if it was a `Nothing`, I have many ways to achieve that in haskell. However I did not find a concise way when I want to apply on it a monadic action.

In this code, to get `d` I can just use `fmap`. But I can't use it to get `c` because that one requires a monadic (`IO` in this case) action to apply on the value in the `Maybe`.

```
import Control.Applicative

main = do
    let x = Just "test.txt"
    let d = reverse <$> x -- good
    print d
    c <- case x of -- verbose
     Nothing -> return Nothing
     Just y -> Just <$> readFile y
    print c
```

This is a way it can be done, but it's also too verbose.

```
    c' <- maybe (return Nothing) (\a -> Just <$> readFile a) x
    print c'
```

I'm sure there's a shorter way, I just can't see it right now...

Comment: Seems that you want to combine two monads (in your case, `Maybe` and `IO`). This is usually done using monad transformers (http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monad-transformers.html). There is an existing `MaybeT` monad transformer, it should help (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html)

Comment: I know about monad transformers but for simple one-off cases it's going to be overkill i think. The case is then shorter and more readable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for `traverse` from `Data.Traversable` -- it's sort of a `sequence`/`mapM` construct applied to monads which are not the list monad (except it's applied to "traversables" and works for things which are weaker than "monads"). So for your particular case the function is just:

```
traverseMaybe f Nothing = return Nothing
traverseMaybe f (Just x) = fmap Just (f x)
```

but `Data.Traversable` defines a more general class:

```
class (Functor t, Foldable t) => Traversable t where
    {-# MINIMAL traverse | sequenceA #-}

    -- | Map each element of a structure to an action, evaluate these
    -- these actions from left to right, and collect the results.
    -- actions from left to right, and collect the results. For a
    -- version that ignores the results see 'Data.Foldable.traverse_'.
    traverse :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
    traverse f = sequenceA . fmap f

    -- | Evaluate each action in the structure from left to right, and
    -- and collect the results. For a version that ignores the results
    -- see 'Data.Foldable.sequenceA_'.
    sequenceA :: Applicative f => t (f a) -> f (t a)
    sequenceA = traverse id

    -- | Map each element of a structure to a monadic action, evaluate
    -- these actions from left to right, and collect the results. For
    -- a version that ignores the results see 'Data.Foldable.mapM_'.
    mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m (t b)
    mapM = traverse

    -- | Evaluate each monadic action in the structure from left to
    -- right, and collect the results. For a version that ignores the
    -- results see 'Data.Foldable.sequence_'.
    sequence :: Monad m => t (m a) -> m (t a)
    sequence = sequenceA
```

This will also work for applicative functors that are not monads, like ZipLists.

Comment: exactly what I wanted and thank you for the extra explanations!

Comment: looking at it now. In fact with GHC 4.10 (base 4.8) I could even use the usual `mapM`, which doesn't anymore necessarily work on lists but on any `Traversable`, including `Maybe`. And `traverse` makes it working even on `Applicative` not only `Monad` functions. I think I got it now :-)

Answer (score 3):

[`traverse`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html) does what you want here:

```
c' <- traverse readFile x
print c'
```